# There is a polynomial $g(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,..., x_n]$ such that $f(X) = g(a_0,..., a_{n−1})$ where $a_i$ is the coefficient of $λ^i$

Tags: polynomials, lie-groups, lie-algebras, characteristic-polynomial

**Let $f: \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial such that $f(AXA^{-1})=f(X)$ for all $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. Prove that there is a polynomial $g(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,..., x_n]$ such that $f(X) = g(a_0, . . . , a_{n−1})$ where $a_i$ is the coefficient of $λ^i$ in the characteristic polynomial of $X$.**

I have been thinking about this problem for a long time and I still can't think of anything to do, I would like someone to give me a suggestion or tell me how I can easily solve this problem.

Comment: How can $f$ be a polynomial, i.e. what is meant by that?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg The problem I have found so, the truth is I do not know very well how to interpret this. That shouldn't be $f: \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})\to \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I am pretty sure that $f$ should have $\mathbb R$ as codomain. Probably what is meant is that $f$ is a polynomial mapping, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_mapping. Besides that, I don't see why to write $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb R)$ instead of $M_n(\mathbb R)$, since the Lie algebra structure seems to play no role here. -- Btw, an almost duplicate of this question but with a nonsensical misunderstanding of the $a_i$ was just posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3594006/96384. What is the exact source of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $f$ is a [polynomial mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_mapping), this statement is closely related to the theory of invariant polynomials. If instead of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ we were looking at a (split) semisimple $\mathfrak g$, this would be a classical description of the $\mathfrak g$-invariant elements of the symmetric algebra $S(\mathfrak g)$ often credited to Chevalley (cf. [MO 182871](https://mathoverflow.net/q/182871/27465)) which further would be shown to be the elements of the symmetric algebra $S(\mathfrak h)$ invariant under the Weyl group: and in the case of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, this are the polynomials in $n-1$ variables which are invariant under permutation of the variables, i.e. the symmetric polynomials, i.e. what comes out here modulo the centre. (And [Harish-Chandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra_isomorphism) linked that further to the centre of the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak g$, but that's not important right now.)

But here's a handwavy proof for the case at hand. First notice that via conjugation it suffices to see how $f$ looks like on matrices in Jordan normal form. Then notice that e.g. the Jordan block

$\pmatrix{\lambda &1\\0&\lambda}$ via conjugation with $A:= \pmatrix{\varepsilon &0\\0&1}$ is brought to $\pmatrix{\lambda &\varepsilon\\0&\lambda}$, so by letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ via continuity (polynomial mapping!) we can further restrict to defining $f$ on diagonal matrices. (There's a complication here because over $\mathbb R$, we cannot even assume that every eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, so there are some technicalities to be filled in. However, one can prove quite generally for any Jordan-Chevalley decomposition $s+n$ that polynomial mappings are $0$ on the nilpotent part $n$.)

So now we assume our polynomial mapping $f$ is defined on the diagonal matrices, i.e. it is basically a polynomial in $n$ variables (one for each entry of the diagonal). But via conjugation with [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), the entries get permuted, i.e. our polynomial has to be invariant under all permutations of the $n$ variables. (Note that this is exactly the same as looking at $S(\mathfrak h)^W$, with $\mathfrak h$ here being the diagonal matrices, as in the general theory.) By definition, these are the [symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial), and it's known at least since Newton that these are all polynomials in the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), which evaluated on the eigenvalues of our matrix are also just the coefficients occuring in the characteristic polynomial.